# How to write a Consumer that counts how many times it was called?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

I need (mostly for testing purposes) to write a consumer whose purpose is to remember how many times it was called. However, I can't do

```
    int i = 0;
    Consumer<Object> handler = o -> i++;
```

because `i` must be final, and I can't increment final variables. I suppose I need something like `MutableInteger` class. What is the right way to count then? Writing my own new class or a new method just for that wouldn't count for a right way.

Comment: Why must `i` be final?

Comment: Because compiler says so: `Variable used in lambda expression should be effectively final`. Because it is accessed from another class.

Comment: Okay, so this is a streams question. Yes, an integer holder should be what you want.

Comment: @chrylis No, this is not a streams question. Consumers are not only used with streams.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an `AtomicInteger` which is implemented using [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

`AtomicInteger` has an `incrementAndGet()` method you can use for this purpose.

It is also useful to know that there are more `Atomic*` variants in the JDK, so there is also `AtomicLong` if `Integer` is not enough for you.

Comment: AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();  Consumer<Integer> = ai::incrementAndGet;

Answer (score 3):

You never could do that. Even with anonymous classes that would not work. You need some object wrapper that will allow you to hold the state, sth like

```
class NumberOfInvocations {
    private int i = 0;

    public void increment(){
       i +=1;
    }
}
```

but you would have to make sure that everything is thread safe, etc, or you could just use AtomicInteger as suggested by Adam.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes where you know that access is single-threaded, a quick and dirty workaround is:

```
int[] i = new int[]{0};
Consumer<Object> handler = o -> i[0]++;
```